# Has vscode/Thunder Client plugin to generate API collection based on API routes of my laravel app?

Tags: visual-studio-code, postman

I moved from postman to vscode with Thunder Client plugin for debugging API in my laravel/php apps

Now I search for plugin/tool like
https://github.com/andreaselia/laravel-api-to-postman

which allows automatically to generate API collection based on API routes of my laravel app,
but for Thunder Client (or maybe some similra API client plugin)...
Are there some similar plugins ?

```
vscode (v.1.85.1)
Thunder Client (v2.20 )
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As an alternative solution - You can import Postman collection into Thunder Client after converting from laraval API

Comment: If there is a way to  import Postman collection into Thunder Client ? Please, details .

Comment: Yes you can import postman collection. Go to Collections Tab, click Menu icon and select import
https://github.com/rangav/thunder-client-support?tab=readme-ov-file#how-to-import-a-collection